# How do I end this while loop with a precision of 0.00001 ([C++],[Taylor Series])?

Tags: c++

I'm working on this program that approximates a taylor series function. I have to approximate it so that the taylor series function stops approximating the sin function with a precision of .00001. In other words,the absolute value of the last approximation minus the current approximation equals less than or equal to 0.00001. It also approximates each angle from 0 to 360 degrees in 15 degree increments. My logic seems to be correct, but I cannot figure out why i am getting garbage values. Any help is appreciated!

```
#include <math.h>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cmath>
double fact(int x){
   int F = 1;
    for(int i = 1; i <= x; i++){
        F*=i;
    }
    return F;
   }
double degreesToRadians(double angle_in_degrees){
  double rad = (angle_in_degrees*M_PI)/180;
  return rad;
 }
 using namespace std;
double mySine(double x){
   int current =99999;
   double comSin=x;
   double prev=0;
   int counter1 = 3;
   int counter2 = 1;
   while(current>0.00001){
    prev = comSin;
    if((counter2 % 2) == 0){
      comSin += (pow(x,(counter1))/(fact(counter1)));
    }else{
      comSin -= (pow(x,(counter1))/(fact(counter1)));
    }
   current=abs(prev-comSin);
   cout<<current<<endl;
   counter1+=2;
   counter2+=1;
   }
   return comSin;
}

using namespace std;
int main(){
cout<<"Angle\tSine"<<endl;
 for (int i = 0; i<=360; i+=15){
 cout<<i<<"\t"<<mySine(degreesToRadians(i));
 }




 }
```

Comment: change int current to  float current  or  double current..

Comment: Also in `fact()` change int F to double F.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example which illustrates how to go about doing this.
Using the pow function and calculating the factorial at each iteration is very inefficient -- these can often be maintained as running values which are updated alongside the sum during each iteration.

In this case, each iteration's addend is the product of two factors: a power of x and a (reciprocal) factorial.  To get from one iteration's power factor to the next iteration's, just multiply by x*x.  To get from one iteration's factorial factor to the next iteration's, just multiply by ((2*n+1) + 1) * ((2*n+1) + 2), before incrementing n (the iteration number).

And because these two factors are updated multiplicatively, they do not need to exist as separate running values, they can exists as a single running product.  This also helps avoid precision problems -- both the power factor and the factorial can become large very quickly, but the ratio of their values goes to zero relatively gradually and is well-behaved as a running value.

So this example maintains these running values, updated at each iteration:

- "sum" (of course)
- "prod", the ratio: pow(x, 2n+1) / factorial 2n+1
- "tnp1", the value of 2*n+1 (used in the factorial update)

The running update value, "prod" is negated every iteration in order to to factor in the (-1)^n.

I also included the function "XlatedSine".  When x is too far away from zero, the sum requires more iterations for an accurate result, which takes longer to run and also can require more precision than our floating-point values can provide.  When the magnitude of x goes beyond PI, "XlatedSine" finds another x, close to zero, with an equivalent value for sin(x), then uses this shifted x in a call to MaclaurinSine.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

// Importing cmath seemed wrong LOL, so define Abs and PI
static double Abs(double x) { return x < 0 ? -x : x; }
const double PI = 3.14159265358979323846;

// Taylor series about x==0 for sin(x):
//
// Sum(n=[0...oo]) { ((-1)^n) * (x^(2*n+1)) / (2*n + 1)! }
//

double MaclaurinSine(double x) {
    const double xsq = x*x;        // cached constant x squared
    int    tnp1      = 3;          // 2*n+1                      | n==1
    double prod      = xsq*x / 6;  // pow(x, 2*n+1) / (2*n+1)!   | n==1
    double sum       = x;          // sum after n==0

    for(;;) {
        prod = -prod;
        sum += prod;

        static const double MinUpdate = 0.00001; // try zero -- the factorial will always dominate the power of x, eventually

        if(Abs(prod) <= MinUpdate) {
            return sum;
        }

        // Update the two factors in prod
        prod *= xsq;                      // add 2 to the power factor's exponent
        prod /= (tnp1 + 1) * (tnp1 + 2);  // update the factorial factor by two iterations
        tnp1 += 2;
    }
}

// XlatedSine translates x to an angle close to zero which will produce the equivalent result.
double XlatedSine(double x) {
    if(Abs(x) >= PI) {
        // Use int casting to do an fmod PI (but symmetric about zero).
        // Keep in mind that a really big x could overflow the int,
        // however such a large double value will have lost so much precision
        // at a sub-PI-sized scale that doing this in a legit fashion 
        // would also disappoint.
        const int p = static_cast<int>(x / PI);
        x -= PI * p;
        if(p % 2) {
            x = -x;
        }
    }
    return MaclaurinSine(x);
}

double DegreesToRadians(double angle_deg) {
    return PI / 180 * angle_deg;
}

int main() {
    std::cout<<"Angle\tSine\n" << std::setprecision(12);
    for(int i = 0; i<=360; i+=15) {
        std::cout << i << "\t" << MaclaurinSine(DegreesToRadians(i)) << "\n";
        //std::cout << i << "\t" << XlatedSine(DegreesToRadians(i)) << "\n";
    }
}
```